# Перенос Qt приложения в Linux

Tags: linux, qt, dll, qtcreator

Добрый день.
Тема, наверное, не нова, но вразумительной инструкции так и не нашел. Выбрал Qt, как инструмент именно кроссплатформенного программирования, для меня это критично. Пока все во фреймворке устраивает, а вот методология сборки либ и переноса на другие машины меня разочаровует. Особенно это касается *nix систем. Если в винде достаточно вручную собрать в папку с бинарником необходимые dll (что само по себе немного напрягает, неужели создатели такой удобной IDE, как QtCreator не смогли добавить инструмент для автоматической сборки всего и вся?), то в Linux я совсем запутался, как создать переносимое приложение без необходимости устанавливать весь пакет Qt на целевой машине? Есть ли доступные пошаговые инструкции? Может кто своими словами втолкует? В Linux ориентируюсь на уровне пользователя. 
Или может есть своя "философия" распространения приложений, о которой я не знаю?
Заранее благодарю сообщество.

Answer (score 3):

Переносимые приложения в линуксе зло. Все приложения должны устанавливатся пакетным менеджером, который и следит за зависимостями, необходимыми библиотеками. Это позволяет не ставить для каждого приложения копии необходимых библиотек.

Это не значит, что Вы не можете его сделать, но нет никакой гарантии, что нужная библиотека будет работать в данном дистрибутиве, которых тысячи.

Я думаю, Вам целесообразнее разобратся с автоматизированными системами сборки, как к примеру Ланчпад для убунты http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/ppa, куда Вы заливаете исходник, а он отдает готовый пакет.

Comment: Только что об этом читал. Такая философия логична и я с ней согласен. Но я не планирую заливать  свою программу в репозитории, по крайней мере пока. Мне бы создать deb или rpm пакет со всеми зависимостями, который я смог бы перенести на другой комп на флешке.

Comment: Я просто приведу начала списка из того, у меня стоит в `~/opt` безо всяких пакетных менеджеров (и очень меня этим фактом радует, не создавая при этом никаких проблем с зависимостями уже не один год): CLion, Eclipse, SQLiteStudio, Komodo IDE...

Comment: Да, из линукса можно сделать свалку как в винде, но не надо.

Answer (score 1):

Для Windows есть утилита winqtdeployment, которая может сложить все явные зависимости в папку с вашей программой.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Я о ней читал, хоть и не пользовался. Жалуются, что не все собирает. Та и конмсольная прога. Для винды я использую DLLCollector. В любом случае, под виндой я могу собрать в кучу все библиотеки, хотя бы и вручную. Вопрос в том, как это делается в линухе.

Comment: В линуксе все ставят с пакетов. Если Вашему приложению нужны so файлы qt, то скорее всего нужно только выполнить `apt install qt-core` или `yum install qt5` или что то подобное.

Comment: Весь вечер курил про пакеты. Как создать deb пакет с бинарником программы на Qt, я понял. Как туда запихнуть библиотеки зависимостей? Например, целевая машина, куда переносится программа не имеет доступа к интернету и установить so-шники Qt из репозитория нет возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в Linux принято не таскать с программой все необходимые библиотеки, а устанавливать их как зависимости. Но в последнее время появились системы сборки, которые позволяют это делать, например [snap](http://snapcraft.io/) и [flatpak](http://flatpak.org/). А еще должна быть возможность прилинковывать нужные библиотеки статически.

Comment: А как эти библиотеки устанавливать как зависимости? Я ещё слаб в *nix системах. К примеру в винде можно создать инсталлятор, который установит в папку саму программу, пропишет ярлыки, скачает и установит необходимые библиотеки, фреймворки и всё это при минимальном вмешательстве пользователя. Как это делается в *nix-ах? Точнее я понимаю, как доустановить тот же qt-core через терминал, но хочется что-то вроде "Далее-Далее-ОК". Если можно сцыль на пошаговую инструкцию.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно задеплоить приложение, для этих целий я использую утилиту 
[cqtdeployer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer)

Установить можно из релизов [github](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases)

или

из [snapstore](https://snapcraft.io/cqtdeployer)

```
sudo snap install cqtdeployer
```

Пользоваться можно следующим образом :

```
cqtdeployer -bin myApp -qmake path/to/my/qmake -qmlDir path/to/my/qml/files/dir
```

Запускать через sh скрипт

Если будите использовать версию из snap то убедитесь что у вас есть все пермишены 
[image: cqtdeployer]

Answer (score 0):

Делал статическую сборку в Windows. Плюс этого варианта - потом не надо каждый раз генерить инсталлятор с библиотеками, на выходе компилятора получаем работающий exe-шник.
Для линукса - практически то же самое, можно один раз заморочиться, и потом компилировать портативную пользовательскую программу (если, конечно, не используются ещё другие специфические системные библиотеки)

Comment: Статическую линковку не рассматриваю по причине использования GPL-лицензии.